# socket.io in a mern app doesn't work when deployed to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a messaging system and I used socket.io to make it real time, with local host it works just fine, but when I deploy it to Heroku it doesn't send messages in real-time anymore.

**Expressjs server code**

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const http = require('http')

const socketIo = require('socket.io')

const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:5000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
        credentials: true,
    }
}
```

**React connection to socket code**

```
useEffect(() => {
      socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
}, [])
```

**EDIT:**
just use the url of your Heroku app instead of localhost in both the client and server, and no need for ports or anything just the link like so: `https://app-name.herokuapp.com/`, and in your client, set the socket variable using `useState` instead of simply assigning values to it.

Comment: change or remove hardcoding localhost

Comment: I did replace all the hardcoded localhost urls to the heroku url, but then when I send a message the deployed application goes down entirely

Comment: Maybe you should use a relative path , " / "